# Debugging Suspend Resume Behavior On Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

My relatively simple C# windows phone 8 application, launches once then fails to load the second time (black screen). I'm assuming there are issues related to the suspend resume but I can't seem to find a way to debug this?

The suspend resume options in the Visual Studio toolbar are disabled for the Windows Phone device and emulator at all times. Is there a console I can use for printouts?
Has anyone else ran into issues with Windows Phone 8 resume from background?

Comment: You can use the `Debug` "console" if your problem happens under the Debugger.

Comment: It only happens when I launch the application manually. It seems the debugger always restarts my app.

Comment: Have you tried manually exiting the app using the hardware keys, but leaving the debugger attached?

Comment: FYI when the debugger is attached and I exit/enter via menus the problem doesn't happen (assuming the process is properly restarted without suspend)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have an actual answer it seems I was testing everything incorrectly. I made changes to the code, ran it in the debugger then launched the app from the icon assuming it matched my changes (it didn't).

Deleting the app and uploading via the application loader allowed me to try various fixes to get the app working. I'm leaving the question open if someone can answer that I'll accept their answer.

Comment: I can confirm that sometimes when you deploy an app through VS it sometimes doesn't update the XAP properly. Just to be sure it runs your latest compiled code, always uninstall app and re-deploy.

As for resuming, I had a problem with a D3D App, related to the fact that my C++ code had static or global variables and upon resuming those still existed and held pointers to the old D3D resources which are deleted when pressing the home button.